# Exception when javascript calls Dart class method

Tags: javascript, dart-html

I want to call Dart class methods from javascript in a web project but this only works using **webdev serve** and not with **webdev build**.  The sample VScode project below reproduces the problem.

The js scriptCmds first gets a handle to a Dart QCmds class by calling getClassHandle, which is declared with an @JS annotated function.  This is then used by two js calls to methods of the QCmds class. Everything works fine when using **webdev serve**, the call parameters are correct and the returned values are as expected.

However when running the same project after building with **webdev build** an exception is thrown:

```
    (index):23 Uncaught TypeError: qs.display is not a function
       at scriptCmds ((index):23)
       at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):14)
```

Is there any documentation on this topic?  Should this be supported with webdev build?

I have a workaround that involves creating a  @JS annotated function for each method and then calling the target method, using a class instance parameter passed from the js. However, I would prefer a much cleaner implementation by calling the methods directly from js.

All the Dart code is in main.dart, built and tested on:

**Dart SDK** 2.14.4 (stable) (Wed Oct 13 11:11:32 2021 +0200) on "windows_x64"
**VS Code** 1.62.3 (user setup)
OS: Windows 10 (Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043)
**Chrome** 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
@JS()
library testcmds;

import 'dart:core';
import 'package:js/js.dart';


@JS('getClassHandle')
external set _getClassHandle(void Function() f);

///
/// The js script first calls getClassHandle to get a QCmds class handle
///
QCmds getClassHandle() {
    // create a QScripter object
    var qcmds = QCmds();
    return qcmds;
}


///
/// main.dart
///
/// In this example a js script (scriptCmds) obtains a Dart class handle 
/// by calling 'getClassHandle' and then calling the class members
/// 'display' and 'mult'.
/// 
/// If built by WEBDEV SERVE, this works just fine.
/// 
/// If built by WEBDEV BUILD, calling a Dart class member from js 
/// throws an exception:
///    (index):23 Uncaught TypeError: qs.display is not a function
///        at scriptCmds ((index):23)
///        at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):14)
///
void main() {
    _getClassHandle = allowInterop(getClassHandle);
}

///
/// A sample class of simple methods to be called by a js script. The
/// script first calls getClassHandle to get a class handle.
///
class QCmds {

    ///
    /// display text 
    ///
    void display(String text) async {
        print('in QCmds.display, text=$text');
    }
    
    ///
    /// multiply a number by 2
    ///
    int mult(int value) {
        print('In QCmds.mult, value = 7');
        return 2 * value;
    }
}
```

Here is the html that includes the js script. Click on the 'click me' button to trigger the js scriptCmds. See the outputs on the Chrome developer tools console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="scaffolded-by" content="https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk">
    <title>testcmds</title>
    <script defer src="main.dart.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }

        #trigger-div {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        }

        #trigger-round {
        padding: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: darksalmon;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='trigger-div'>
        <div id='trigger-round'>
            <input type="button" value="Click me" id="script_trigger" onclick="scriptCmds()"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>open developer tools console to see results</p>

    <script>
    function scriptCmds() {

        // first get the class handle
        var qs = getClassHandle();

        // call the display command (as class member)
        qs.display('some text');

        // call the mult command (as class member)
        var result = qs.mult(7);
        console.log('result=' + result);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and pubspec.yaml:

```
name: testcmds
description: Testing javascript js calling a Dart function
version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.14.4 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.3

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.1.2
  build_web_compilers: ^3.2.1
  js: ^0.6.3
  lints: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm sitting in the same boat

Comment: No comments here but I did get a response on github.  See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47855